# Languages having same word to denote "count" and "think"

Tags: etymology, list-of-languages

In Tamil, there is a single word எண்(eN) which means 'count', 'number', 'think'. I am wondering if this is unique to Tamil? I am wondering if the other old classical languages have a similar word.

Comment: In English *count* has one sense of *think*, "consider, regard as": "I count him an honest man." Is the Tamil word employed for *think* in other senses?

Comment: In Spanish, _contar_ is a verb meaning to count (numbers), with a derived noun _la cuenta_ 'the bill', for which one asks at a restaurant. _Contar_ also means 'to tell a story'. This is very similar to [the English meaning of _account_](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/style.pdf): _do the accounts, account for every purchase, give an account of, his account of his experiences,_ etc. It is not at all uncommon for them to have those two meanings. Perhaps it's because stories are pan-human, while accountancy isn't.

Comment: @jlawler Native English *tell/tale* also doubles this way. I've always fancied it's because a narration 'adds' up the particular actions one after another.

Comment: Also Hebrew: 'sefer' = a book, 'sippur' = a number. The root SFR has broadly the same range of senses as "cont-" in Romance (from Latin "computare") and "zahl/tell" in Germanic.

Answer (score 5):

The English word "reckon" has the same two meanings.

Comment: OP asked for "old classical languages". ;-)

Answer (score 3):

This is the case for Russian.

The word *считать* `[ɕːɪˈtatʲ]` has two meanings:

1. *to count* as in *"I **counted** my cats; fifteen are they"*;
2. *to consider, to think* as in *"I **think** that I'm too fat"*.

The etymology dictionaries (Vasmer) provide with the following explanation (note the **Old Indic origin**):

> < Old Indic `сḗtаti` «to comply, think, discover, understand», `kḗtas` «thought, idea, will», `cikitvā́n` «understanding, knowing»,
>   Avestan `čikiθwā̊` «wise»

Comment: I don't think Vasmer is claiming that the Russian word is of "Old Indic origin". I think he is saying that the two words are cognates.

Answer (score 3):

The English verb *to ponder* carries the two meanings of *to think, mull over* and *to weigh, measure*, from Latin *pondus* "weigh", which gave both the Italian verbs *pensare* and *pesare*, "to think' and "to weigh" respectively.